# Два равных double не равны

Tags: php, математика, if, float, double

Всем привет, столкнулся сегодня с бредовой ошибкой, суть такова :

Есть две переменных **$prevBalFlo**(текущий баланс) и **$pay_float**(сумма платежа). Если на **балансе** денег больше или равно **сумме платежа** - порядок.

Код :

```
<?php

//...

$prevBalFlo=    (float) $this->balFloByAccountGet($account);//echo $prevBalFlo.SLN;
$pay_float  =   (float) $pay_float;

$isBalFloEnough_BOO =   $prevBalFlo >= $pay_float;


/*2195*/btw::logWrite('['.__LINE__.']isBalFloEnough_BOO:['.(int) $isBalFloEnough_BOO.'];prevBalFlo:['.$prevBalFlo.']('.gettype($prevBalFlo).');pay_float:['.$pay_float.']('.gettype($pay_float).');account:['.$account.'];');
/*2196*/btw::logWrite('['.__LINE__.']'.($pay_float > $prevBalFlo).';'.($pay_float == $prevBalFlo).';');

//...

?>
```

На домашней машине полный порядок(PHP/5.4.9) на VPS(PHP/5.4.45) вот такая картина :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PHP говорит, что 4800 больше чем 4800. Я с ума схожу?

Comment: Не используйте плавающие типы для денег.

Comment: @vp_arth А как быть с центами и копейками?

Comment: Храни всё в целых копейках, или даже в десятых копейки. Заведи класс Money, в конце концов.

Comment: @vp_arth Спасибо, идея хорошая.